Feedback for my first project - sqlserver-json-tools
could you review my first project on github please. The JSON_MODIFY function in SQL Server 2016 and 2019 does not allow creating paths dynamically, making it necessary to chain JSON_MODIFY executions. In this project I tried an easier way to create json objects using TSQL through functions as in the example:
https://github.com/dbacriativo/sqlserver-json-helpers
Sample:
DECLARE @INPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{}'
SELECT dbo.[JSON_OBJECT](@INPUT, 'this.path.not.exist', '{"dir":"c:\\"}')
 -- output {"this":{"path": {"not": {"exist": {"dir":"c:\\"}}}}}


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JSON_OBJECT](@JSON NVARCHAR(MAX), @PATH NVARCHAR(255), @VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- VALIDATIONS
    IF ISJSON(@VALUE) <= 0
    BEGIN
       RETURN 'O Parâmetro @VALUE precisa ser um objeto json válido';
    END;

    -- SETUP JSON
    IF ISNULL(@JSON,'') = ''
    BEGIN
       SET @JSON = '{}';
    END;

    SET @PATH = REPLACE(@PATH, '$.', '');

    -- IF PATH EXISTS AND IS PROPERTY
    IF JSON_VALUE(@JSON, CONCAT('$.', @PATH)) IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
       --RETURN 'PROPERTY'
       SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, CONCAT('$.', @PATH), JSON_QUERY(@VALUE))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       -- IF PATH EXISTS AND IS OBJECT OR ARRAY
       IF JSON_QUERY(@JSON, CONCAT('$.', @PATH)) IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN
          --RETURN 'OBJECT OR ARRAY'
              SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, CONCAT('$.', @PATH), JSON_QUERY(@VALUE))
       END 
       ELSE
       BEGIN
          --RETURN 'PATH NOT EXISTS'
          -- PATH NOT EXTISTS NEED TO BUILD PATH
          DECLARE @TBLPATH TABLE (ID int identity, NAME varchar(255));
          DECLARE @LEVELS INT = LEN(@PATH) - LEN(REPLACE(@PATH, '.','')) + 1;
          DECLARE @JSON2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
          DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(255);
          DECLARE @CURPATH VARCHAR(255) = '$';
          DECLARE @ID int = 1;

          -- SPLIT PATH INTO PIECES
          INSERT INTO @TBLPATH
             SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PATH, '.')

          -- LOOP ON EACH PIECE OF PATH
          WHILE @ID <= @LEVELS
          BEGIN
             SELECT @NAME = NAME
               FROM @TBLPATH
              WHERE ID = @ID;

             -- CREATE PATCH
             IF JSON_QUERY(@JSON, @CURPATH) IS NULL
             BEGIN
                SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, @CURPATH, JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('{"', @NAME, '": null}'))); 
             END;

             -- UPDATE CURRENT
             SET @CURPATH = CONCAT(@CURPATH, '.', @NAME);

             SET @ID = @ID + 1;
          END;

          -- UPDATE TREE
          SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, CONCAT('$.', @PATH), JSON_QUERY(@VALUE))
       END;
    END;

    -- UPDATED JSON
    RETURN @JSON;
END;


Please edit your title to describe the purpose of your code: codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

backwhacks
SELECT ... '{"dir": "c:\\"}'
If your use case permits it, prefer c:/ forward slash.
It avoids backwhacked quoting nonsense,
where each level of evaluation cuts the number of slashes in half.
Also, for didactic purposes, consider replacing this/path/not/exist
with a simple some/path.
As near as I can tell, the existence / non-existence of the path
seems to be immaterial to the result produced, and to the teaching
value of the example.
magic number
... , @PATH NVARCHAR(255), ...

I imagine there's a good reason for that number.
Maybe it's part of a spec, or we want to avoid 16-bit lengths.
Recommend you spell out the details,
in case some hapless maintenance engineer revisits this code
a year or two down the road.
I am reading the corresponding JSON_OBJECT function:

Description:
This function is used to add or update a text value at the specified JSON path within a JSON object. This function is more versatile, where it is possible to enter a Json Object, or Text, value. It also has support for including items in arrays.

In another context we might call this javadoc or a docstring.
(Sorry, I don't know the proper name for it in a t-sql context.)
I truly do thank you for offering this helpful advice.
But what I'm really looking for is a
promise,
a description of what hoops caller must jump through, and
what lovely result caller can rely on receiving.
These sentences hint at that, without being explicit.
I appreciate the wonderfully explicit
precondition
we find here:
    -- VALIDATIONS
    IF ISJSON(@VALUE) <= 0 ...

I am slightly surprised that we're contemplating negative
return values, given that the function
spec
says this boolean predicate shall

Returns 1 if the string contains valid JSON; otherwise, returns 0. Returns null if expression is null.

type stability
Or we might refer to this as meaning stability.
We pass in @JSON, which means one thing.
And then we mutate and return @JSON, having an entirely different meaning.
(It turns out that, due to deeply nested ELSE clauses,
once we decide on a new value we never reconsider @JSON again.)
Recommend you invent a new variable, perhaps @RET,
for the returned value.
I do thank you for helpful comments such as these:
       --RETURN 'PROPERTY'
       ...
          --RETURN 'OBJECT OR ARRAY'

extract helper
This function is starting to get Too Long,
as one cannot read all of it without vertical scrolling.
Consider breaking out the 'PATH NOT EXISTS' logic
as a private helper function.
That would give you an opportunity to offer a separate
explanation about inputs and outputs for the helper.
Recommend you elide "obvious" comments such as -- UPDATE CURRENT.
nit, typo: EXTISTS
